# Rest endpoint /eureka/apps/delta is not returning delta correctly after updating metadata of registered eureka clients

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix, netflix-ribbon

I am updating the eureka metadata with key as **weight** with **some value** using endpoint ***/eureka/apps/${app-name}/${app-id}/metadata?weight=40***. I am calling this update metadata api **once** for each of my registered service instances(eureka client registered with eureka) in a **loop**(registered instances are two and it can be more). Simultaneously, I am continuously hitting the endpoint **/eureka/apps/delta** but this endpoint sometimes returning the response with the updates I have done using update metadata api and sometimes its not.

Just to re-verify my above result, I have deployed zuul application, registered it with eureka and customized the Ribbon configuration- getting the **servers from loadbalancers** and **from returned server fetching InstanceInfo object** and printing **InstanceInfo.getMetadata** . This also sometimes giving the correct updated metadata and sometimes not.

**Note** : I am using Spring cloud version Edgware.SR4

Have a look at this snapshot
[Response of /eureka/apps/delta after update metadata call.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCVji.png)

Comment: eureka is eventually consistent and between caches in eureka server, eureka client and ribbon it can take between 90 seconds and two minutes to get an update.

Comment: @spencergibb I have waited more than 20 minutes still it didn't picked up the updates.
Also, I am continuously hitting /eureka/apps/delta - delta changes has not appeared. And as per eureka server `responseCacheUpdateIntervalMs` which is 3 mins by default, the delta changes are not appearing even after 10 mins.

The issue is pretty much replicable.

Comment: Any comments @spencergibb ??

Comment: nope, I've never seen that before and don't have any idea why.

Comment: @spencergibb Ok. This is pretty much replicable.

Comment: Can you provide a [complete, minimal, verifiable sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem?  It should be available as a GitHub (or similar) project or as a zip file.

Comment: @spencergibb I had raised the issue on Github. Here is the ticket on the netflix repository : https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/issues/1173 and ticket on the spring-cloud-netflix repository : https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/3347.

Comment: Please close one of the issues.

Comment: Sure. But @spencergibb could you please escalate the issue since you are one of major contributor to spring cloud netflix. I havent seen such activity on the Netflix repo and any response from Ryan on spring cloud repo.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by using disabling delta : "disableDelta: true". Thought, it might be helpful for someone else.
A word of caution : disabling delta will increase the traffic b/w eureka clients and eureka server.